# Bash Script - sourceFile not printing to targetFile

Tags: bash

The following code should be printing the contents of the sourceFile to targetFile, line by line, with each line having in front 'wireless-key s:', but it only prints 'wireless-key s:' to the targetFile.

```
#!/bin/bash
sourceFile="file1.log"
targetFile="/etc/network/interfaces"
numLines="$(wc -l < "${sourceFile}")"
counter=5
lineNumber=5
if (( counter >= "$numLines" )) || [[ ! -f "${sourceFile}" ]]; then
        echo "invaild file" >82; exit 1
fi
while [ "$counter" -le "$numLines" ]; do
        sed -i "${lineNumber} s/.*/wireless-key s: $(sed -n ${counter}p <<< " ${sourceFile}")/" "${targetFile}"
        counter=$((counter + 1))
done
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

perhaps a different approach...

> awk '{print NR,"wireless_key",$0}' srcfile > dstfile